Why does $W = \int F\cdot \mathrm{d}s$ rather than $\int s\cdot\mathrm{d}F$
Conventionally, infinitesimal work is defined as $\delta w = F\cdot ds$ and its integral as the work $$w(P_1 \to P_2) = \int_{P_1}^{P_2} F\cdot ds \tag{1}.$$
The word work, of course, can be assigned to anything, it is just a definition, but does the other infinitesimal quantity defined as $\delta w^* = s\cdot dF$ or its corresponding integral between the same points $P_1,P_2$: $$w^*(P_1 \to P_2) = \int_{P_1}^{P_2} s\cdot dF \tag{2}$$ have physical significance (meaning), and if yes what?

This question is similar to: Why is small work done always taken as $dW=F \cdot dx$ and not $dW=x \cdot dF$?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@gandalf61 why not write this into an answer?

@gandalf61 neither the original question, or my editing, defined what was meant by $F$ and $s$, it only assumed that some $Fds$ could represent infinitesimal work. In that spirit, $F$ could be taken as position dependent "force", that is a potential field (gravitational, electric, magnetic, thermal, chemical, pressure, etc.), and $s$ is the corresponding "mass" or "charge" moving in it; now both $w$ as "work" and $w^$ as "lost work" are very meaningful independently of the reference coordinate system. ($w+w^=d(Fs)$ is a total differential, and $w^*$ is the Legendre transform of $w$.)

@Confuse-ray30 When I originally posted my comment the question was closed. Now that it has been re-opened I have deleted my comment and replaced it with an answer.

Thank you all for the editing! I notice in Qmechanic's version they discuss infinitesimal work. I wonder however why we can't define it as a limit approaching zero. Would this make it more accurate? N.B. My knowledge is slight in this area. All I know is that limits are more rigorous in calculus than the infinitesimal definition.

I will assume that, following the usual definition of work, $F$ is a force and $s$ is displacement from a fixed origin.
The problem with assigning a physical meaning to $s \cdot dF$ is that the value of $s$ depends on where you place the origin of your co-ordinate system (whereas $ds$, being a difference of two $s$ values, does not). A physically meaningful quantity should not be co-ordinate dependent.
